# JPA processing row by row with locking

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, transactions, locking

I have a problem with JPA (Postgres db). Let's assume we have a table like:

```
id | data
 1 | aaa
 2 | bbb
 3 | ccc
 4 | ddd
```

It is kind of a queue and I want to process it like a queue (please do not ask why). I have multiple applications that will 'consume' that data. And I would like to allow them to work concurrently.

What I need to do is to read the first row from the table (can be any, not necessarily the first one), process it and finally remove it from the table. Second application/pod should not access the row currently processed by the first one.

Also, when the first pod processes the row, I do not want to lock the entire table.

Let's assume I have two pods: P1 and P2:

- P1 starts processing row number 1,
- P2 wants to execute the same logic, but it shouldn't see the row number 1 (which is currently under processing by P1), it should retrieve and handle row number 2.

How to achieve that with JPA? I tried some JPA queries with `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` but I am locking the entire table then (second app waits till I leave `@Transactional` block in the first one).

If there was a query to delete a row and return the deleted data - it would be the easiest approach with proper transaction level.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE locking the entire table on you? You need to debug what the SQL issued is, what your database supports, and what a row level lock might mean to other tables/data that might also need access, and possibly show how you are using it. There is no atomic read/delete and commit operations, though you might be able to keep track of an offset using a sequence, or separate table to mark offsets - see MQ implementations

Comment: I did some debugging already and I see that hibernate adds `FOR UPDATE` to the query. The query is generated from `findFirstBy()` JPA method.

Comment: I was thinking about adding a table or some columns to the existing one like: `under_processing` and maybe also `update_stamp` to detect rows stuck in processing. But I was told to keep it as simple as possible without adding anything else.

Comment: findFirstBy is not a JPA method; you mean Spring repository default. If that is over something that isn't tied to a particular indexed row, your database is likely applying a table lock so that other processes cannot make changes that would affect those query results. Use the ID to lock a particular row!

Comment: Actually, I did more investigation and looks like I eventually got what happens here. `findFirstBy` works fine - it generates a query like: `SELECT id, data FROM my_table LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE`. The second pod executes the same query and gets stuck on a lock of the first row (which is already locked).
EDIT: I can select a different row from another transaction in the meantime.

Comment: I could go directly with IDs, but how to select a first row which is not locked? Otherwise I will jump into exactly the same issue...

Comment: you have to look at how other message queues work and reinvent the wheel or reuse what they have as best you can. Best I can think of is to mark a row as being processed in one transaction, then process it in a separate one in the same thread. Your query to get the next one would need to filter out rows being processed. And since it is two transactions, you'll want a mechanism to pick up rows that were being processed but the thread that was doing the work died or failed. This is what is used for many large batch fetch processing, where each process gets a page of data to work on.

Comment: You can probably then avoid using pessimistic locking, and use optimistic locking to detect conflicts in that initial state update transaction. The last to attempt to change the state of a record would just fetch the next unprocessed record (set) and try again.

Comment: With a new column, to mark rows being processed, the problem becomes quite straightforward.

Comment: But, I managed to find one more interesting thing in Postgres - `SKIP LOCKED`. It works with a query like this: `SELECT id, data FROM my_table LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`.
Thanks @Chris!